# How to make this type of border using CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make this type of border using CSS3?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, you need to use an image and the border-image property.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Answer (score 1):

I test a hack for make this, with two div the fist one make the border with a background linear gradient. And the second one is use to put your content on.

Ther is my CSS snippet :

```
div {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.border {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, white 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, white 75%, white ), 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, white 75%, white );
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

And you can take a look to my fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/zSnDG/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a good read on border-image property.

http://ejohn.org/blog/border-image-in-firefox/